# Jquery, Opera. How to stop submit?

Tags: jquery, textboxlist

i'm using this control 
http://devthought.com/projects/mootools/textboxlist/

**It's using JQuery**

Code:

```
bit.toElement().keydown(navigate);
 var navigate = function (ev) {
    var evStop = function () {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();
    };

    switch (ev.which) {
    case 13:
        evStop();

        ...work...
    }
};
```

This code work fine in FF and IE, on pushing Enter it's stop form submit.

**Q: But in Opera, page reload, how to fix that?**

**Solution:** bit.toElement().**keypress**(navigate);

Comment: Are we using Mootools or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you could include a "return false", to the function.

In case, this works.

Try to change "keydown" by "keypress".

Try this:

```
$(document).bind("keydown keypress", function(event) then e.preventDefault() won't work try.. event.preventDefault()
```